# How to select from table ordering by primary key

Tags: haskell, persistent

I have this SQLite persitent schema:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Entry
  class EntryClass
|]
```

This maps to a following `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "entry"
  ( "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  , "class" INTEGER NOT NULL);"
```

I've manually added the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword to be sure that identifiers are always monotonically increasing. Now I want to pick the oldest entry from the database - that's the one with lowest identifier.

If I would write SQL I would say something like this:

```
SELECT id, class FROM entry ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

But I have problems translating this query to persistent. It should look something like

```
nextEntry <- selectFirst [] [Asc EntryId, LimitTo 1]
```

but this gives me a syntax error complaining about the fact that there is no data constructor `EntryId`. Indeed `EntryId` is a type synonym for `Database.Persist.Class.PersistEntity.Key Entry`, so it cannot be use in the `Asc` data constructor, which has a type `forall typ . Asc (EntityField record typ)`.

So the question is how could I make persistent order my query results by table's primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should actually work; `EntryId` is *both* a type and data constructor. For example, the following code (just tweaked from the synopsis of the [persistent chapter of the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#persistent_synopsis)) compiles just fine:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
import Control.Monad.IO.Class  (liftIO)
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Persist.TH

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Show
|]

main :: IO ()
main = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do
    runMigration migrateAll

    johnId <- insert $ Person "John Doe" $ Just 35
    janeId <- insert $ Person "Jane Doe" Nothing

    selectList [] [Asc PersonId] >>= liftIO . mapM_ print
```

Comment: Ooops, it seems that I forgot to export a data constructor `EntryId` from my entities module. After doing proper exports it turned out that my code compiles well. I was also somewhat misleaded by generated template haskell splices and didn't noticed that there actually exists an EntryId data constructor only seeing the type synonym. Sorry for that :(